# struts2 tiles javascript loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, tiles

I'm using in my demo project strut2-tiles-plugin, my tiles is looking like

```
<definition name="profileListPanel" extends="basePanel">
<put-attribute name="title" value="menu.adm.pro.title"></put-attribute>
<put-list-attribute name="body-items">
<add-attribute value="/jsp/admin/profile/profileList.jsp"/>
</put-list-attribute>
</definition>
<definition name="profileList" extends="baseLayout">
<put-attribute name="title" value="menu.adm.pro.title" />
<put-list-attribute name="body-items">
<add-attribute value="profileListPanel" type="definition"></add-attribute>
</put-list-attribute>
</definition>
```

in basePanel i'm iterating

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="body-items" toName="bodyItems"/>
    <s:iterator var="item" value="%{#attr.bodyItems}">
        <tiles:insertAttribute value="${item}" flush="false"></tiles:insertAttribute>
    </s:iterator>
```

in profileList.js I have

```
var editPopUp;
$(document).ready(function(){
    editPopUp=new PopUp();
    $('.edit-profile').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url=$(this).attr('href');

        editPopUp.openPopUp(url);
    }); 
});
```

Problem is:
profileList.js is loaded multiple times
and `$('.edit-profile')` has attached more than one event

Some ideas ?

Comment: Where do you load `profileList.js`?

Comment: in profileList.jsp i have this script

Comment: I thought that problem can be when i'm interating, remove iterations, and problem also persist